# Retrieve Exif Data From UWP Capture without Saving to Disk

Tags: c#, uwp

Currently, I am capturing a photo and getting a the metadata using the following code:

```
using (var imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
   await _capture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), imageStream);
   var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(MediaBuilderSettings.GetScratchDirectory());
   var storageFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
   var storageFileStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
   await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(imageStream, storageFileStream);
   List<string> imageMetaRetrieveList = new List<string> { "System.Photo.Aperture", "System.Photo.Brightness" };
   IDictionary<string, object> extraProperties = await storageFile.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(imageMetaRetrieveList);
}
```

Is there a way that to access the exif data without saving the image to disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with ExifLib. It support the tag reading from the memory stream like following.
It works with my Win8.1 StoreApp project. UWP also works.. maybe.

[ExifLib - nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExifLib/)

```
using ExifLib;
...
using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    using (var reader = new ExifReader(stream))
    {
        object value = null;
        string exifstr = "";
        // ISO
        reader.GetTagValue<object>(ExifTags.ISOSpeedRatings, out value);
        if (null != value && typeof(UInt16) == value.GetType())
        {
            exifstr += ("ISO" + value.ToString());
        }
        ....
```

Comment: Was hoping for a solution without a 3rd party lib, but this looks like it will do the trick. Thanks.